# How to setblock snow_layer only if block below is a full-block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Or is there actually any way to do that?

Basically I do a `/setblock ~ ~ ~ snow_layer` at the player but if it's above something that snow layer can't be on (eg. slab,sign,grass) it just looks buggy. :/
I could avoid it with causing a block update right after creating it.

Any idea is helpful even if you're not sure if it works or not! (best would be a one command block method)

As you can see on the picture looking for `{OnGround:true}` doesn't solve it all the time:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I could do a `/setblock` above it, but that may remove other block, so I'm looking for a safer idea.

**UPDATE 2:**
Changed title to represent the problem more clearly.

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your question a bit to better reflect the actual problem: how do I use setblock at a player's location, but only when they're standing on a full block? Don't presume the solution, it only serves to narrow the answers you'll get.

Comment: Thank you, I just thought that detecting a full block is nearly impossible or only with a million command blocks containing each full-block.
Causing a block update would do the dirty work :P

Comment: I was just searching for the same thing, I want a command to make it add snow layers on top of full blocks when it's snowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple method

Run the following 2 commands [sequentially](https://www.reddit.com/r/redstone/comments/236an3/help_are_these_two_command_blocks_triggered_at/cgwto99) in 1 tick:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ snow_layer 0 keep
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ snow_layer 0 clone ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ replace force
```

First command places snow layer at player's position, and second command will update the snow layer and remove improper ones. **Using this method will constantly update adjacent blocks around the block that the player's head is in, if you don't want that use advanced method instead.**

---

#### Advanced method

1. First you need to allocate 2 blocks(at `<x> <y> <z>` and `<x> <y+1> <z>`) on your world to this command block system. Which should be independant and kept away from any other blocks or entities.
2. Following commands will run [sequentially](https://www.reddit.com/r/redstone/comments/236an3/help_are_these_two_command_blocks_triggered_at/cgwto99) in 1 tick when done (works best with 20Hz fill/clone clock):

   > `/execute @p ~ ~.999999999999999 ~ clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~ ~ <x> <y> <z> replace`
   >   `/setblock <x> <y+1> <z> snow_layer 0 keep`
   >   `/clone <x> <y> <z> <x> <y> <z> <x> <y> <z> replace force`
   >   `/execute @p ~ ~.999999999999999 ~ detect <x> <y+1> <z> snow_layer 0  setblock ~ ~ ~ snow_layer`
3. Replace `<x> <y> <z>`, `<x> <y+1> <z>` with allocated blocks' coordinates from above

Comment: This one is just brilliant! With mine you see snow_layer glitching while standing on top of stairs or chests, but your way is just absolutly what i was looking for!

Comment: @Feca1997 Updated my answer to fix adjacent blocks constantly updating, also simulated `onGround:true` with fine-tuned coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, but I use your old solution, because I wanted to use minimum number of commandblocks and I also liked that it was more flexible without allocating blocks.

Comment: The simple method won't work on world border, though it's usually not a big matter

Answer (score 9):

After trying many things, I finally came up with a solution that works all the time (I hope) and doesn't change any block:

Instead of creating the snow layer with:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ snow_layer
```

I use the command:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:snow_layer",Time:1,DropItem:false}
```

wich does the job quite well, and because of `DropItem:false` it doesn't even drop the snow if placing it fails. :)

**NOTE:**

Summoning falling sand at the same block where there's an existing one will cause it to be deleted, so only summon the sand if there's air! In my example:

Summon FallingSand that become a snow_layer AT every player:

`/execute @a ~ ~ ~` **detect ~ ~ ~ air 0** `/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {...}`

Comment: And I thought fallingsand summons were pretty much dead when setblock existed. Very, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

> I could do a /setblock above it, but that may remove other block, so I'm looking for a safer idea.

The `/setblock`command allows for an old block handing mode of "keep", which means that it will only replace air. Because of this, we can safely use a block that will immediately turn back to air (like a snow_layer) to cause a block update. Running a command like this at the same time as your current one should fix things:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ snow_layer 0 keep
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't update the snow layer if it doesn't change the block. Thank you anyways. ^^